# How can I break- line in Custom JSX Tag imported from another class in following snippet:

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

```
             <Experience
           startYear={2019}
           endYear={2019}
           jobName="First Job"
           jobDescription="1. Providing API calls support for Headless CMS.2. Provide escalated ticket/incident management support"
           />
```

Here, I wanted to break line after 2nd point, I tried '\n' and br, this Tag is Made in JSX by following code:

```
       import React, { Component } from 'react';
       import { Grid, Cell } from 'react-mdl';

       class Experience extends Component {
          render() {
             return(
                <Grid>
                <Cell col={4}>
                   <p>{this.props.startYear} - {this.props.endYear}</p>
                </Cell>
                <Cell col={8}>
                  <h4 style={{marginTop:'0px'}}>{this.props.jobName}</h4>
                <p>{this.props.jobDescription}</p>
                </Cell>
               </Grid>
             )
         }
     }

     export default Experience;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go by passing a jsx component as a prop to the child, instead of just raw text. This gives you more flexibility and control of how the UI will be rendered/ordered, within the parent component.

```
const Parent = () => (
    <Child 
        jobDescription={(
           <div style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
              <div>1. Providing API calls support for Headless CMS.</div>
              <div>2. Provide escalated ticket/incident management support.</div>
           </div>
        )}
    />
)

const Child = (props) => (
    <div>
       <div>Child specific stuff</div>
       {props.jobDescription}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Todor, this had been helpful, Thank you for your support! I got what I needed to have and learned a lesson from this.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array, then loop the array to output

for each item. Using string wont work because it is escaped when goes into props. Although Im aware that it might not be suitable for job description field.

Or, use you can write html tag in the string then render using https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but in this case, this is not the correct solution I had been looking for,  Nikko